# file upload browser in thumbnail view

Tags: html, facebook, file-upload, browser, web

i'm trying to write a piece of code that will allow a user to open a file browser and select files to upload to a site. is there a way to make sure the file browser always opens in thumbnail view? In windows the view is the same as the last view that was used.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I see that in Facebook it always opens as thumbnails no matter the last view that was used, so how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the HTML5 features and may not work with old browsers.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload-image" multiple="multiple"></input>
 <div id="upload" class="drop-area">
   Upload File
 </div>
 <div id="thumbnail"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.drop-area{
width:100px;
height:25px;
border: 1px solid #999;
text-align: center;
padding:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#thumbnail img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:5px;
}

canvas{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
console.log(fileInput);
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
var files = this.files
showThumbnail(files)
},false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
 $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
 e.preventDefault();
 },false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 },false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
},false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

var dt = e.dataTransfer;
var files = dt.files;

showThumbnail(files)
},false);

function showThumbnail(files){
 for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
  var file = files[i]
  var imageType = /image.*/
  if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
   console.log("Not an Image");
   continue;
 }

var image = document.createElement("img");
// image.classList.add("")
var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
image.file = file;
thumbnail.appendChild(image)

var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = (function(aImg){
  return function(e){
    aImg.src = e.target.result;
  };
}(image))
var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
image.onload= function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
}}}});
```

Comment: what your code does, if i got it right, is generating thumbnails after an upload. what i'm looking for is to open the file selection in thumbnail view always, regardless of the last view that was used by the user. like it's done in FB.